# SQL Statement - Trying to base a where clause off of a case statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a where clause based on a case statement. I am getting a multi-part identifier "k.Author" Could not be bound.

I did some research and found that the where clause is processed before the Case statement so I put the case statement in a sub Query. The Sub Query ends as K and the column ends as Author.

can someone Help me figure out how I can get this working. I only want the columns to show where K.Author = 'Coordinator 1,Referrals'.

Error

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 42
The multi-part identifier "k.Author" could not be bound.
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT MCON.MailHeader_DateSent,
       VP.Person_Name AS [Patient Name],
       MCON.MailHeader_Subject,
       COUNT(MCON.MailHeader_ID) AS [Inboxed Mesage]
       MTA.MailDetail_Folder,
       EP.Person_Name AS [To],
       N.Note_DateOccurred,
       CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), --Missing a Column Alias here
       CASE WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%ashlee%' THEN 'Ashlee ' + CHAR(10) + 'Castro' --I have assumed the line break mid name is meant to be there
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%cordova%' THEN 'Adrian ' + CHAR(10) + 'Cordova'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%lyndsay%' THEN 'Lyndsay ' + CHAR(10) + 'Frommer'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Lyndsay%' THEN 'Lyndsay ' + CHAR(10) + 'Frommer'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%rivera%' THEN 'Rivera ' + CHAR(10) + 'Margaret'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Margaret%' THEN 'Rivera ' + CHAR(10) + 'Margaret'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Jtroy%' THEN 'Jennifer ' + CHAR(10) + 'Troy'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Adrian C%' THEN 'Adrian ' + CHAR(10) + 'Cordova'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Ann B%' THEN 'Ann ' + CHAR(10) + 'Burdge'
            ELSE 'N/A' 
      END AS [Referal Agent],
      (SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(CN.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Coordinator 1, ' + CHAR(10) + 'Referrals%' THEN 'Coordinator 1, Referrals' --Assumed same about line break here
                   ELSE 'Not A Referral Note'
              END AS 'Author'  
      FROM CHRT_Note CN) AS k
FROM MSG_MailHeader MH
     JOIN MSG_MailDetail MD on MCON.MailHeader_ID = MTA.MailHeader_ID
     JOIN ENTY_Person EP on MTA.Entity_ID  = EP.Entity_ID
     JOIN TASK_TaskAttachment TA on MCON.MailHeader_ID = TA.MailHeader_ID
     JOIN View_Patient VP on TA.Patient_ID = VP.Patient_ID
     JOIN CHRT_Visit CV on VP.Patient_ID = CV.Patient_ID
     JOIN CHRT_VisitCPT CVC on CV.Note_ID = CVC.Note_ID
     JOIN CHRT_OtherNote CON on TA.Patient_ID = CON.Patient_ID
     JOIN CHRT_Note N on CON.Note_ID = N.Note_ID
WHERE MTA.MailDetail_Folder = 3 
  AND MCON.MailHeader_DateSent BETWEEN '1/22/2018' AND '1/22/2018 23:59:59' 
  AND EP.Person_Name = 'Coordinator 1, Referrals'
  AND CVC.VisitCPT_Code IN  (...RemoveTA.. For example)
  AND N.Note_DateOccurred > MCON.MailHeader_DateSent
  AND k.Author = 'Coordinator 1, Referrals'
GROUP BY VP.Person_Name,
         MCON.MailHeader_DateSent,
         MTA.MailDetail_FolderP.Person_Name,
         N.Note_DateOccurred,
         MCON.MailHeader_Subject,
         CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

Comment: Please consider adding some formatting to your SQL. That is far from easy to read. You also have some stray asterisks (`*`) in your SQL, which will be generating errors.

Comment: Your `k` is an alias for a field pulled out of a subqery, not a table

Comment: Do you want K as a column or another table to JOIN on?  At the moment, it is neither (except by accident or fluke - if it returns only one row it is fine as a column)

Comment: try using `cross apply` instead of using subquery in select list, it will enable you to reuse it in `where` clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, now that I've foratted the SQL to something readable, yes the others are right, you don't have a table called or aliased `k`. You do, however, have a column with an alias of `k` (which you won't be able to reference in the `WHERE` clause by alias).

The others are, again, right, use `CROSS APPLY`. Thus, you end up with this:

```
SELECT MCON.MailHeader_DateSent,
       VP.Person_Name AS [Patient Name],
       MCON.MailHeader_Subject,
       COUNT(MCON.MailHeader_ID) AS [Inboxed Mesage]
       MTA.MailDetail_Folder,
       EP.Person_Name AS [To],
       N.Note_DateOccurred,
       CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), --Missing a Column Alias here
       CASE WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%ashlee%' THEN 'Ashlee ' + CHAR(10) + 'Castro' --I have assumed the line break mid name is meant to be there
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%cordova%' THEN 'Adrian ' + CHAR(10) + 'Cordova'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%lyndsay%' THEN 'Lyndsay ' + CHAR(10) + 'Frommer'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Lyndsay%' THEN 'Lyndsay ' + CHAR(10) + 'Frommer'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%rivera%' THEN 'Rivera ' + CHAR(10) + 'Margaret'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Margaret%' THEN 'Rivera ' + CHAR(10) + 'Margaret'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Jtroy%' THEN 'Jennifer ' + CHAR(10) + 'Troy'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Adrian C%' THEN 'Adrian ' + CHAR(10) + 'Cordova'
            WHEN CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Ann B%' THEN 'Ann ' + CHAR(10) + 'Burdge'
            ELSE 'N/A' 
      END AS [Referal Agent],

FROM MSG_MailHeader MH
     JOIN MSG_MailDetail MD on MCON.MailHeader_ID = MTA.MailHeader_ID
     JOIN ENTY_Person EP on MTA.Entity_ID  = EP.Entity_ID
     JOIN TASK_TaskAttachment TA on MCON.MailHeader_ID = TA.MailHeader_ID
     JOIN View_Patient VP on TA.Patient_ID = VP.Patient_ID
     JOIN CHRT_Visit CV on VP.Patient_ID = CV.Patient_ID
     JOIN CHRT_VisitCPT CVC on CV.Note_ID = CVC.Note_ID
     JOIN CHRT_OtherNote CON on TA.Patient_ID = CON.Patient_ID
     JOIN CHRT_Note N on CON.Note_ID = N.Note_ID
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(ca.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%Coordinator 1, ' + CHAR(10) + 'Referrals%' THEN 'Coordinator 1, Referrals' --Assumed same about line break here
                              ELSE 'Not A Referral Note'
                         END AS Author
                   FROM CHRT_Note ca) AS CNca
WHERE MTA.MailDetail_Folder = 3 
  AND MCON.MailHeader_DateSent BETWEEN '1/22/2018' AND '1/22/2018 23:59:59' 
  AND EP.Person_Name = 'Coordinator 1, Referrals'
  AND CVC.VisitCPT_Code IN  (...RemoveTA.. For example)
  AND N.Note_DateOccurred > MCON.MailHeader_DateSent
  AND CNca.Author = 'Coordinator 1, Referrals'
GROUP BY VP.Person_Name,
         MCON.MailHeader_DateSent,
         MTA.MailDetail_FolderP.Person_Name,
         N.Note_DateOccurred,
         MCON.MailHeader_Subject,
         CAST(N.Note_SummaryRTF AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

Note, I have changed your aliases. When using an Alias, use something representative. Calling a table `a`, then the next `b`, the next `c`, etc, isn't going to help anyone. Anyone looking at your query will have to look at your `WHERE` clause to find out what an alias is every time they see an alias (not just one off scan). If you have 3 tables called `Customer`, `Sale`, and `CustomerSale`, then alias them something like `C`, `S` and `CS` respectively, and stick to those alias through your solution. Those aliases actually mean something.

Otherwise, `Customer` might be `a` in one query, as it's the first table in your `FROM` clause, but `c` or even `e` in another, because it's the 3rd or 5th.

Comment: Thanks for the example and the advice on how I can improve my queries!